# How to wrap textview depending on length?

Tags: android, textview

I have a Textview which has different length depending on the input of the users.
When I press ok to calculate, the textview goes one line below.What I want to do is to wrap the textview to show up on one line. So far I have done smth like this:
android:ellipsize="none"
android:singleLine="true"
but the problem is that the remaining textview doesnt show up.
Is there a way to wrap the width when the textview is long and to expand it when short?

Comment: If the textsize is exceeds than screen's width. And, if you want to show that text on singlLine. You've to show that text as marquee style only.

Answer (score 3):

you can use marquee for text view like this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:textColor="#ff4500"
    android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't show a `TextView` all together on a **singleLine** more than the width of your phone's screen unless you use marquee. As an alternate, wrap your `TextView` in a `HorizontalScrollView`